# Angular JS custom directive not working on iOS devices

Tags: ios, angularjs, deployment, angularjs-directive

I have deployed my app on Azure, I have a C# backend and AngularJS front end.
I am using a custom directive (called `bgSrc`) which sets the image source based on the given url (either a `background-image` or a `src`) depending on which element the directive is used.

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('bgSrc', ['preloadService', function (preloadService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.hide();

            preloadService(attrs.bgSrc).then(function (url) {
                if (element[0].tagName === 'DIV' || element[0].tagName === 'MD-CONTENT' || element[0].tagName === 'MAIN' || element[0].tagName  === 'FORM') {
                    element.css({
                        "background-image": "url('" + url + "')"
                    });
                    element.fadeIn();
                }
                else if (element[0].tagName === 'IMG') {
                    attrs.$set('src', url);
                    element.css({
                        'display': 'block'
                    });
                    element.fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is my preloadService:

```
app.factory('preloadService', ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    return function preload(url) {
        var deffered = $q.defer(),
            image = new Image();

        image.src = url;

        if (image.complete) {

            deffered.resolve(image.src);
            $rootScope.loading = false;

        } else {
            $rootScope.loading = true;

            image.addEventListener('load', function () {
                deffered.resolve(image.src);
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            });

            image.addEventListener('error', function () {
                deffered.reject();
                $rootScope.loading = true;
            });
        }

        return deffered.promise;
    };
}]);
```

Here is an example of how I use it on html.

```
<div ng-if="!loading" bg-src="assets/build/img/ocean_bg.png">
    <form name="model.form" ng-submit="login()" bg-src="assets/build/img/scroll.png">
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

It works perfectly well on Chrome and Android but keeps failing on iOS devices. I have pinpointed the issue to be my custom directive, if I remove it the page loads fine, if I include it the page is caught in an endless loop not loading my images and stick in the "`$rootScope.loading`" state which simply displays a circular progress bar.

Any help on the matter is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my preloadeService, where the loading of the image was stuck in an infinite loop.